# Docker Deployment Issue: "unable to set PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT"

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to deploy my Django application through Docker. When I build it in the terminal (`docker-compose -f docker-compose-deploy.yml up --build`), everything is successful until I get this error:

```
dockerdeploymenttest-app-1    | !!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
dockerdeploymenttest-app-1    | your memory page size is 4096 bytes
dockerdeploymenttest-app-1    | detected max file descriptor number: 1048576
dockerdeploymenttest-app-1    | lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
dockerdeploymenttest-app-1    | unable to set PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT
dockerdeploymenttest-app-1 exited with code 1
```

This is stopping my project from being deployed, and I can't seem to figure out why.
Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.8-alpine

ENV PATH="/scripts:${PATH}"

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp gcc libc-dev linux-headers
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp

RUN mkdir /TeenSocial
COPY ./TeenSocial /TeenSocial
WORKDIR /TeenSocial
COPY ./scripts /scripts

RUN chmod +x /scripts/*

RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/media
RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/static

RUN adduser -D user
RUN chown -R user:user /vol
RUN chmod -R 755 /vol/web
USER user

CMD ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./TeenSocial:/TeenSocial
    command: sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
```

docker-compose-deploy.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes: 
      - static_data:/vol/web
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=samplesecretkey123
      - ALLOWED_HOSTS=127.0.0.1, localhost
  
  proxy:
    build:
      context: ./proxy
    volumes:
      - static_data:/vol/static
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - app

volumes:
  static_data:
```